# py to exe with pugubu

Tags: python, exe

I got the exe file using pyinsttaller.
but in the running I got the following error:

```
No module named 'pygubu.builder.ttkstdwidgets
```

[image: Error Picture]
and *exe* file is not running .
the *exe* and *ui* file are at the same location.

Comment: it seems the executable was produced from python using nuitka. There are known issues where nuitka didn't include the required files :tkinter.ttk module. The executable might need to be redone again.

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain ? how should I do the exe file correctly?

Comment: see the log of the same issue here: https://github.com/alejandroautalan/pygubu/issues/62. You will notice that the issue involves making sure nuitka imports all ttk modules which Pygubu doesn't do very well. You standalone .exe doesn't have all the module required to run.

Answer (score 1):

Error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygubu.builder.tkstdwidgets'`

I encountered this error when trying to run a python app built with cx_freeze. My solution was to explicitly import the missing module:

`from pygubu.builder import tkstdwidgets`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used tk and ttk packages, so I simply added 2 packages to my source as below. Finally this error was cleared

---

### from pygubu.builder import tkstdwidgets,ttkstdwidgets

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

pyinstaller file.py --collect-all "pygubu" --hidden-import pygubu.builder.tkstdwidgets

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).